# Losing Visual Effects settings after reboot

Tags: compiz, desktop-background

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 10.10 from 10.04 and ran into a problem. If I right click on my Desktop, select Change background it takes me to the Appearance Preferences and then I go to the Visual Effects tab to change my effects from None to Normal, now this all works fine, as soon as I restart my computer it changes back to None again, does anyone know how come this is and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi
Look at thread #5 in this bug, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/500570 . This solved my issue.
//Stefan